# Survival Analysis with time-varying covariates in R with the mlr package

Tags: r, mlr, survival

is it possible to implement time-varying covariates in survival analysis with the mlr package like the method described in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf?

Comment: This is a really broad question, and not suited to the SO model, as in the  [SO help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). I hope you find a helpful answer elsewhere

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: currently not supported see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357172/mlr-survival-analysis-with-time-dependent-data#comment95723423_54357172 and GitHub links in comments